# SVG's and Text not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So, I have a countdown timer, it's mobile responsive,however, it doesn't work on iPhones.I tested it from an android phone,it looks perfectly fine,however,on my iphone,the text property from my code doesn't really show up how it's supposed to,i'm guessing because "x" and "y" property doesn't work,anyone knows the necessary -webkit- , i couldn't find it on Google. Thanks in advance. My code is :

```
<svg class="svgCountDown">
    <text class="days" x="40" y="-40" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:20px;" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="baseline">'+(days == '' ? 0 : days)+'</text>
    <text class="days" x="40" y="-38" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:10px;" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="hanging">days</text>
    <circle r="38" cx="40" cy="40" stroke="red" fill="none"></circle>
    <circle class="d" r="38" cx="40" cy="40" style="stroke-dashoffset:229px; stroke-dasharray: 239px;"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can u create a minimal working example and put it in the question itself instead. so that we can test the issue.

Comment: `the text property from my code doesn't really show up how it's supposed to`...how is showing up and how is supposed to show up? Agreed with the first comment.

Comment: Some SVG text attributes are not supported in Safari - experiment with taking text anchor and alignment baseline out and manually positioning using x and y